# Is there a command to split lines in Vim?

Tags: vim, vi

In Vim, the <kbd>J</kbd> key joins two lines together. Is there a similar, built-in, key combination to split lines with a newline (at the cursor position, or similar)?

Alternatively, what would be the most robust way to define a key combination to do that (in normal mode, not insert mode)?

Comment: **See also**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624821/vim-split-line-command

Answer (score 38, accepted):

No, there's no built-in command for that.

When I want to split on a `<Space>`, I do `r<CR>`.

--- EDIT ---

@keith-nicholas' comment reminded me about this question. FWIW I came up with an hopefully "universal" method in the mean time:

```
function! BreakHere()
    s/^\(\s*\)\(.\{-}\)\(\s*\)\(\%#\)\(\s*\)\(.*\)/\1\2\r\1\4\6
    call histdel("/", -1)
endfunction

nnoremap <key> :<C-u>call BreakHere()<CR>
```

Comment: Using `r<CR>` is simply clever! Thanks!

Comment: that's great!  super annoying going into insert to insert lines

Comment: I found `s<CR>` keeps indentation whereas `r<CR>` does not.

Answer (score 8):

`a` <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> to split to the right of the cursor, or `i` <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> to split to the left.

Comment: That is it. Just insert a single newline. Alternatively: use r+<return> to replace the character under the cursor with a newline. Would be nice to have a single letter command for it, but as far as I know there isn't one.

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way I've found to split lines in Vim is the normal mode command `gq` (type both letters in quick succession in normal or visual mode):

- In visual mode, it will split whatever is selected.
- In normal mode, you follow `gq` with a motion.

For example, `gql` will split one line to the currently set width. To set the width of the split lines to be different from your current setting, you can use

```
:set textwidth=<n>
```

Where n=number of characters you want in a line, e.g., 10, and change back to your normal width when you're done.

Got this information from a Youtube video by Kholidfu that shows how to join and split lines in normal mode using a motion: [Vim Tutorial - Join and Split Lines](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MA9WFO_WUOM).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `s` substitute request with the `\r` carriage return. Consider a file with this sentence at line one:

```
This is sentence one. This is sentence two.
```

Then this will split the sentences into two lines:

```
:1s/\. /\r/
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define your own using map. To define z as the command for example:

```
:map z i<CTRL+m>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few tips and starting points, with some overlap on existing answers:

- wrap current line after 70+ characters (on a word boundary): `:s/.\{-70,\}  */&^M/g`

  - note: `{-70,}` is the [non-greedy quantifier](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html)
  - the `^M` is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> (a "return")
  - prefix with `%` to operate on the whole file, e.g., `:%s/.\{-70,\}  */&^M/g`
  - create mappings in `.vimrc`, eg, use `MM` to run: `map MM :%s/.\{-70,\}  */&<C-V><C-M>/g`
  - instead of `:%s` for search/replace, one could also use the [global command `g`](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Power_of_g) *(see below)*
- in practically the same way, the single command `gql` will [break the current line into multiple lines](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Format_only_long_lines), using the line width to determine where to break (eg `:set tw=80`), but this won't work on the whole file, as it also joins shorter lines into longer ones ( [see here for details](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Format_only_long_lines) )

  - use `:g/./ normal gqq` to avoid the concatenation
- if you install the paragraph formatter utility `par` (ie, `sudo apt install par`), you can use it to format lines of code by invoking it from within `vim`

  - `:g/.\{80,\}/ .!par w70`
  - translation: use the "global" command `g`, find lines 80+ characters, run them through `par`, w/ max width `70`

Answer (score 0):

You can record a macro:

in normal mode type "q+" to start the record.
press "i", the macro you want to record.
then press "q" again to stop recording.

to use the macro go to normal mode and type "@+letter".

in my case I used the "b" to use this macro:
to record type in normal mode "qbiq"
to use type in normal mode "@b"